# Why does my listview behave strangely in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have created an adapter for a `ListView` in android which behaves really strange. The listview is passed a list of objects, which is sorted by some rule (comparing numbers, wow...). Now, when the list is shown in the view duplicate entries are shown, they are not sorted, entries are missing, and when I scroll the list even entries change! What is going on?

Here is the code of the adapter, I can post more code if that is necessary:

```
public class StatViewAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<Entry> entries;

    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtOK;
    TextView txtNOK;
    TextView txtHist;
    TextView txtPrandom;
    TextView txtPhist;
    TextView txtPtotal;

    //public StatViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    public StatViewAdapter(Activity activity,  ArrayList<Entry> entries){

        super();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.entries = entries;

        Collections.sort(this.entries, new Comparator<Entry>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2) {
                if (o1.getPriority() > o2.getPriority()) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (o1.getPriority() < o2.getPriority()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;

            }
        });

        for (int i=0;i<this.entries.size();i++) {
            String name = this.entries.get(i).name();
            int p = this.entries.get(i).getPriority();
            System.out.println(String.format("%s:  %d", name, p));
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return list.size();
        return this.entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.entries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater=this.activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView == null){

            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);

            txtName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listname);
            txtOK=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listok);
            txtNOK=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listnok);
            txtHist=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listhist);
            txtPrandom =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listprandom);
            txtPhist=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listphist);
            txtPtotal=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listptot);
        }

        Entry entry = this.entries.get(position);
        txtName.setText(entry.name());
        txtOK.setText(Integer.toString(entry.number_ok));
        txtNOK.setText(Integer.toString(entry.number_nok));
        txtHist.setText(entry.history);
        txtPrandom.setText(Integer.toString(entry.randomIndex));
        txtPhist.setText(Integer.toString(entry.histIndex));
        txtPtotal.setText(Integer.toString(entry.getPriority()));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Obviously, because you are storing references to views of item directly in Adapter

Comment: what? can you explain? Its not obvious to me...

Comment: Analyze what would happen if convertView is not null but is not the same as last view returned from getView

Comment: I have not the slightest idea!

Comment: Maybe it would work?

Comment: Too hard? All views references would be references to previous view not current...  That's why viewholder pattern exits (not only)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133839/discussion-between-alex-and-selvin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` is to bind the data of the object at the given `position` to a view. The view might be a recycled one (`convertView`) or you need to create one in the method. The problem is that you should not keep references to those views (`txtName`, `txtOk`) in the `Adapter`.

```
public class StatViewAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<Entry> entries;

    //TextView txtName;
    //TextView txtOK;
    // ...

    public StatViewAdapter(Activity activity,  ArrayList<Entry> entries){
    // ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=this.activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);
        }

        TextView txtName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listname);
        TextView txtOK=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listok);
        // ...

        Entry entry = this.entries.get(position);
        txtName.setText(entry.name());
        txtOK.setText(Integer.toString(entry.number_ok));
        // ....

        return convertView;
    }
```

It works but it still isn't a good way to do it, you might want to use a `RecyclerView` or implement the `ViewHolder` pattern.

The idea of the `ViewHolder` pattern is that you don't have to call `findViewById` every time you bind a view because it's computationally expensive and it could make the scroll laggy.

You might want to use a `RecyclerView` because it's a newer and more flexible view that does the same job of a `ListView` and it has the `ViewHolder` pattern built-in.

Comment: Nope, does not work. I see the same result. Maybe I have to clean the project. One moment ...

Comment: Ok this seems to work. But why is this not a good way. What is a `RecyclerView`? I don't want to recycle a view, just to present the data in the listview....?

Comment: I edited the answer for why it's not a good reason, also if it helped please consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Seems I have to read some docs about this complicated stuff and those Views. Not today...